# calculate slope in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This question is just about calculating the slope at each timestep in a dataframe. There's a lot of extra detail here, that you are welcome to peruse or not, but that one step is all Im looking for.

I have a forecast and an observed dataframe. I am trying to calculate the "interesting" changes in the forecast.

I'd like to try to accomplish that by:

- calculate the best fit of the observed data (ie, linear regression).
- find its slope
- find the difference between the slope and the slope at each moment of the observed data

To do this, I need to generate the slope at each moment in the time series.

- calculate the stddev and mean of that difference
- use that to generate z-scores for the values in the forecast DF.

How do I calculate the slope at each point in the data?

### original

```
from sklearn import linear_model

original = series.copy() # the observations
f = y.copy() # the forecast

app = ' app_2'

original.reset_index(inplace=True)
original['date'] = pd.to_timedelta(original['date'] ).dt.total_seconds().astype(int)    

# * calculate the best fit of the observed data (ie, linear regression).
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# * find its slope
reg.fit(original['date'].values.reshape(-1, 1), original[app].values)
slope = reg.coef_

# * find the difference between the slope and the slope at each moment of the observed data
delta = original[app].apply(lambda x: abs(slope - SLOPE_OF(x)))

# * calculate the stddev and mean of that difference
odm = delta.mean()
ods = delta.std(ddof=0)

# * use that to generate z-scores for the values in the forecast DF. 
# something like
f['test_delta'] = np.cumsum(f[app]).apply(lambda x: abs(slope - x))
f['z'] = f['test_delta'].apply(lambda x: x - odm / ods)

# from that I might find interesting segments of the forecast:
sig = f.index[f['z'] > 2].tolist()
```

Comment: Would you like show us sample data and the expected output ?

Comment: all the numbers are normalized -- they are values between 0 and 1.

Comment: I added a lot of clarity to the post... I dont think specific numbers are important. .. [0,0.5,2,3.5,4.5,5.5,6,6.5,8,9], [10.2, 11.4, 12, 16, 13.5] would be fine input values ... getting a collection back with only 16 would be the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "calculate the slope at each point in the data," the simplest is to compute "rise over run" for each adjacent row using `Series.diff()` as follows. The resulting Series gives (an estimate of) the instantaneous rate of change (IROC) between the previous and current row.

```
iroc = original[app].diff() / original['date'].diff()
```

Also, you don't need `apply`. Thanks to numpy vectorization, `scalar - array` behaves as expected:

```
delta = slope - iroc
```

Hope this works. As Wen-Ben commented, it would really help to see actual data and your expected output.

Comment: I thought that looked elegant and just perfect, but when I apply it and then calculate zscores: `original['z'] = delta.apply(lambda x: x - odm / ods)` the min and max value in that range are both negative. That shouldnt be possible right? they should be normally distributed around 0

Comment: Just needs parentheses for proper order of operations :) `lambda x: (x - odm) / ods`. This can be achieved without `apply(lambda)` as well.